# Does the 11th or 12th Doctor ever fight all his enemies at once?

Tags: doctor-who

That episode with the Pandorica box had me hoping for an epic battle between the Doctor and all those who showed up to take the box.

Comment: I don't wanna go against your intention so I won't edit myself, but "all" is a pretty big list. The answer to it is also categorically "no" (referring to the question title). Maybe changing "all" to "a lot of" you'd get a wider variation (even more so by allowing any doctor not just 11 and 12, but again, depends on what you're looking for :) )

Answer (score 11):

It happens in ["Time of the Doctor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_of_the_Doctor) but mostly off screen. That Wikipedia link reads as follows:

> Lying that he won't send Clara back again, the Doctor does so and she
>  returns to Earth as the siege of Trenzalore becomes an all-out war. As
>  the centuries pass, most of the races depart or are destroyed, leaving
>  only the Silence (with whom the Doctor joins forces, putting aside
>  their feud) and the Daleks.

I would put the end of that episode as a pretty good example of an epic fight against his enemies as well.

Comment: by the *end* of that episode he's only left fighting the Daleks, but the *middle* of that episode is a decent answer to the question.

Comment: It has been a while since I saw the episode so I was not entirely sure. Thanks.